# How do I check that a window opened by Selenium was closed by the user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am using Selenium, which opens a window. Now before doing any further steps, I want to test whether the window is still open or is closed by the user. How to detect that window is still open?

If window is closed it raises `NoSuchWindowError`

and this is my driver

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = require('selenium-webdriver').By,
    until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()   
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build()
```

Comment: Can you share you attempt at solving this problem? It will make it easier for you to obtain a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Get window handles. Check it's size and you can determine how many windows have been opened at that point of time.